# Crear un array en PHP

Tags: php

Hola actulemnte tengo una duda este es mi codigo `php` para hacer mi array :

```
<?php

$tra = new area();
$madres = $_POST['mesa'];
$reg = $tra->traer_area($madres);
if (count($reg) == 0) {
    $data['data'] = array();
} else {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($reg); $i++) {
        $data['data'] = $reg;
    }
}
print_r($data);
?>
```

Y el resultado es :

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [nombre_completo] => YOLANDA MEJIA ROJAS ) [1] => Array ( [nombre_completo] => IRMA VARA SANCHEZ ) [2] => Array ( [nombre_completo] => DIANA AGUAYO MORENO ) ) )
```

Lo que deseo es que me salga asi;

```
  ["YOLANDA MEJIA ROJAS","IRMA VARA SANCHEZ","DIANA AGUAYO MORENO"]
```

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario iterar con un for, simplemente usa array_columns y te devuelve todos los valores

```
<?php

$tra = new area();
$madres = $_POST['mesa'];
$reg = $tra->traer_area($madres);
if (count($reg) == 0) {
    $data  = [];
} else {
   $data =array_columns($reg, 'nombre_completo');
}
print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: gracias por la correción, me equivoqué de variables

Comment: Es verdad , no es necesario iterar el _array_ .

Comment: Hasta donde conozco, la función es en singular `array_column()`.

Answer (score 0):

### El problema:

Al iterar el arreglo `$reg`, en la variable `$data['data']`:
- Estas pisando su valor en cada `loop` en lugar de agregar un valor.
- Estas asignando siempre el arreglo `$reg` completo, en lugar de un valor específico del mismo.
Al imprimir el arreglo `$data`, no estas indicando la posición `data`.

### Solución:

- *Opcional*: Podrías iterar el arreglo devuelto por `$tra->traer_area` usando `foreach` para simplificar tu código.
- Agregar al arreglo `$data['data']` usando la sintaxis `$data['data'][]`.
- Indicar que deseas agregar al arreglo `$data` un valor específico del registro dato.
- Llamar a `print_r` sobre `$data['data']` para obtener el resultado deseado.

Así por ejemplo:

```
$tra = new area();
$madres = $_POST['mesa'];
$regs = $tra->traer_area($madres);
$data['data'] = array();
foreach($regs as $reg) {
    $data['data'][] = $reg['nombre_completo'];
}
print_r($data['data']);
?>
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/ICMC64055)</kbd>